# ElasticSearch Unassigned Shard

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 nodes in elastic search cluster with 8 CPU and 16 GB RAM. I have set ES_HEAP_SIZE to 10 GB.

In my yml configuration file on both machines i have set

```
index.number_of_shards: 5
index.number_of_replicas: 1
```

And both machines are allowed as master/data true.Now problem is my 0th shard of node 1 is unassigned after restart.I tried

```
for shard in $(curl -XGET http://localhost:9201/_cat/shards | grep UNASSIGNED | awk '{print $2}'); do
    echo "processing $shard"
    curl -XPOST 'localhost:9201/_cluster/reroute' -d '{
        "commands" : [ {
              "allocate" : {
                  "index" : "inxn", 
                  "shard" : '$shard', 
                  "node" : "node1", 
                  "allow_primary" : true
              }
            }
        ]
    }'
done
```

it does not give any error and says acknowledged true and show status of shard to initialize but when i view shard its still uninitialized.

Am I doing anything wrong in setting? Should I make both node as master/data true and on both machines set shard:5 and replica:1

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I notice you are using port 9201, are you sure you have one node running on the machine? Check with GET /_cat/nodes to see the amount of nodes.

Comment: Hi , i am using port 9201 on node1 because on 9200 there are two nodes are running with same index and data with system generated names. I provided cluster name and node name but i am not able to find how 9200 has two * Jack Frost & m Alfie O'Meggan nodes running on 9200. So in my cluster node1 i gave 9201 port.

Comment: Kindly check your `yml` file configuration... wether is has disabled the multicast or not. if possible please provide me the yml configurations

Comment: if you enable the multicast then it automatically bind join with the same cluster which is running in the network

Answer (score 0):

I did a trick to solve the same , I renamed 0 folder under indices on node1 and did a force full assign 0th shard on node1 and it worked for me.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9201/_cluster/reroute' -d '{
        "commands" : [ {
              "allocate" : {
                  "index" : "inxc", 
                  "shard" : 0, 
                  "node" : "node1", 
                  "allow_primary" : true
              }
            }
        ]
    }'
```